# Login screen changed in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, login-screen, lock-screen

I use an HP Probook 4440s 64bit laptop with Windows 8 Enterprise installed. There is also a utility called HP Security Tools and I enabled a password protect option from it. Doing that somehow changed the normal Windows 8 lock screen to look something like this:

[image]

I removed the Sparekey functionality but the screen persists. And I dont know how to change it as the settings only shows the general personalization of the "lock screen" and not the "login screen".

Any help please?

Comment: Rather than editing your question, just answer it and accept your own answer. It's made for it.

Comment: Levans : I did not have the required reputation to do that then.

Comment: @Pawan - You do now.  You really should post an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, found the solution myself. Posting it here for further reference.

Once you activate the Spare Key protection, the Windows Logon checker is added to HP Protect Tools. So disabling the Spare Key doesnt take away the login screen, which is a result of added layer of protection.

To bring back the old, normal login screen, open HP Client Security --> Credentials Manager --> Configure Now

You will first need to remove the Spare Key protection, if any.

Then, click on the "Administration" button on the bottom of the left sidebar. Administration --> Administration Console --> Increase System Security --> Uncheck the "Windows Logon security".

And its done. That was all.